# Save the argument value at the first call of the function in Java

Tags: java

Let's say I have a function with a certain argument, and I want to save the value of this argument at the first time the function is called. The most obvious way to do this is by a boolean flag:

```
boolean functionAlreadyCalled = false;
int firstArgument = 0;

void func(int argument) {
   if (!functionAlreadyCalled) {
      firstArgument = argument;
      functionAlreadyCalled = true;
   }
}
```

Is there a more elegant (possibly Java-specific) way to do this, without using an additional variable?

Comment: your question is logic specific and can be set in multiple ways. so there can be multiple answers for your question you need to use the most relevant one.

Comment: Could you give some information on why you would like to do this? It's quite likely there are better ways of achieving what you want to do.

Comment: sprinter, I have a class of a gaming agent that is initialized outside the game and enters the game at a certain moment. It must remember some of the parameters of the game at the time of its entry.

Comment: vikeng21, can you elaborate? I'm not sure I understand what you mean by logic-specific, and I do want to understand what's wrong with the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Integer instead of int and check if the attribute value is null or not.

```
Integer firstArgument = null;

void func(int argument) {
   if (firstArgument == null) {
      firstArgument = argument;
   }
}
```

Comment: OP did not specify where `firstArgument` is declared, so it *could* be right.

Comment: Why do you think that it's very wrong? It's not thread safe, etc. but the OP didn't explained the context.

Comment: I added the initialization (although there isn't a specific integer value that can indicate the variable wasn't initialized - except infinity perhaps). TheLostMind, could you explain what's wrong about the approach?

Comment: I prefer this solution instead of storing 2 attributes. A lot of developers are afraid of boxing/unboxing but you will *never* find an application that is slow because of boxing. Finally, primitives might completely disappear in Java 10. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/javaposse/_BaextZgOuA

Comment: @PacoAbato - Ok. I should not have been so *over scrupulous*. What if some other method needs to use `firstArgument `? and change its value?. Also, boxing values is not always a good thing. You are typically giving it another option (`null`), so the OP will have to check for `null` values of `firstArgument` in all places where it is being used (`unboxing might give NPE). This will actually require lot of code changes. I strongly suggest using a separate flag / indicator instead of *deriving* conclusions based on values that the program needs in many places.

Comment: @Venomouse - The answer lies in how many other places `firstArgument ` is being used. If `methodX` is being called before `func()`, and it takes an int as an argument, then you will need an additional null check. As a thumb rule, always use *primitives instead of their boxed types unless it is necessary (collections)*.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle - and they should be *afraid*. Changing *primitives* to their *boxed types / wrappers* leads to aditional null checks in places where they are used. Also, the hit on performance is *imminent*

Comment: @TheLostMind, other methods use firstArgument, but never change its value. I'm not sure I can assume they won't be called before func().

Comment: @Venomouse - In that case you will have make sure that the unboxing of `firstArgument` won't cause a NPE. If you ask me, separate the *controlling / flow* logic from  *business / core* logic. Don't reuse fields just because you want to create *less number of fields*. Tomorrow you might completely remove `firstArgument` and add a double value instead of it. Or you might have to pass `firstArgument` to some other method. Just because one method needs *some check*, don't let your entire system become one big system which could blow up when you try to extend it.

Comment: @TheLostMind I do not agree with null checks. You always have to check if the value is initialized, with a null check or with a boolean check like in the OP question. Using primitives is dangerous because you cannot know if it is initialized or not except if you add a boolean to keep track of it. This is an extra work and highly error prone. More, in case you do not verify, the program will not raise any error. This is a silent bug.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle - With existing code, if the OP has to call `methodX()` and `methodY()` before calling `func()`, and these methods try to assign value of `firstArgument` to an *int* field, how would you go about it?

Comment: Maybe the new [Optional](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html) class in Java 8 would be an interesting feature in this case.

Comment: @TheLostMind If you try to assign it before it is initialized, I prefer a NPE to a silent wrong value.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle - A *boolean* flag will not even *interfere* in this case. It does its work only when `func()` is called. Thus the call to other methods *prior to func()* need not be checked for anything.. and will not break anything.. A silent wrong value?. `0` can be a valid value right?

Comment: @TheLostMind It seems to be another use case. If the use case assumes that the value can be returned as 0 if not initialized, an `int`  is indeed a good solution.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle - Ok.. My suggestion was to separate *controlling* feilds from *business / core* fields. To have a clean design, the *functionality* of each field should be well defined. A field should not do more than what is expected from it. If the field `firstArgument ` is being used *as part of program logic*, then it is better not to use it as *controlling flag*. - Clearly define what each field must do :)

Answer (score 0):

See first it depends whether you want to initialize whenever a new object is created or once for all i.e. if once initialized then set same for every object. Hence writing solution for both the cases.

First approach:-

```
public class ArgumentTest {
    boolean functionAlreadyCalled = false;
    int firstArgument = -1;

    public ArgumentTest(int i){
        func(i);
    }

    public static void main(String... q){
        ArgumentTest arg = new ArgumentTest(1);
        ArgumentTest arg1 = new ArgumentTest(2);
    }

    void func(int argument) {
        if (!functionAlreadyCalled) {
          firstArgument = argument;
            System.out.println("Initialization Called");
          functionAlreadyCalled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

This gives output :-

> run:
>
> Initialization Called
>
> Initialization Called

Second Approach :-

```
public class ArgumentTest {

    private static volatile ArgumentTest arg = null;
    boolean functionAlreadyCalled = false;
    int firstArgument = -1;

    private ArgumentTest(int i){
        func(i);
    }

    public static ArgumentTest getArgumentTest(int i){
        if(arg == null){
            arg = new ArgumentTest(i);
        }

        return arg;
    }

    public static void main(String... q){
        ArgumentTest arg = getArgumentTest(1);
        ArgumentTest arg1 = getArgumentTest(2);
    }

    void func(int argument) {
        if (!functionAlreadyCalled) {
          firstArgument = argument;
            System.out.println("Initialization Called");
          functionAlreadyCalled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

whereas this gives :-

> run: Initialization Called